# Accessing MacBook local network from iPhone

Tags: macos, networking, mac, iphone, localhost

I have a development environment with grunt and BrowserSync which gives me the URL `192.168.1.140:3000` to access the webpage from other devices in the same network.

The URL works on the MacBook, but when I try to access it on my iPhone, it loads for 60 seconds and says:

"**Safari could not open page because the server stopped responding**".

The same happens when I try to access
`MacBook-Air.local`
(as the settings suggest) or `192.168.1.140` directly.

Both devices are connected to the same WiFi-Network, I also disabled the Firewall on the Macbook, didn't help.

Any ideas on what the problem could be?

Answer (score 0):

Well, looks like restarting the router finally solved the problem.

Comment: personally i try always to avoid to take a restart as answer, but in this time i think is a valid answer because seems to be a soho router and with that hardware you are unable to restart services(not always), you are free to take your own answer as valid and give the green mark.